# How can I modify the documents on an object-level in find() before I publish them?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to modify the documents matched in the find() cursor in my publish method. However, it should not be saved into Mongo.

Example:

Email.find({}) returns a document like 
{email: "hello@hello.com"} which matches a record in the Mongo's collection.

But I would like to do an extra step, that is to check if the email is verified (which could be in another collection, or some logic procedure, and append it like this.

That is to say, I would like to publish

{
    email: "hello@hello.com",
    is_verified: true
}

while the document in Mongo remains {email: "hello@hello.com"}

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Docs = new Meteor.Collection('docs', {

     transform: function(doc) {

         ...
         return anythingYouWant;
     },

});
```

or

```
var docs = Docs.find({...}, {

     transform: function(doc) {

         ...
         return anythingYouWant;
     },

});
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection and http://docs.meteor.com/#find .

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection), if you read carefully,  `transform` is not the correct solution to the question asked:

> Documents will be passed through this function before being returned
>   from **fetch or findOne**, and before being passed to callbacks of
>   observe, map, forEach, allow, and deny. **Transforms are not applied** for
>   the callbacks of observeChanges **or to cursors returned from publish
>   functions**

The proper solution for transforming documents in a publication is to use a package like [maximum:server-transform](https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/server-transform):

```
$ meteor add maximum:server-transform
```

```
Meteor.publishTransformed('allDocsTransformed', function() {
  return Docs.find().serverTransform({
    extraField: function(doc) {
      // use fields from doc if you need to
      return 'whatever';
    }
  });
});
```

...or **DIY** the same by writing a custom publication, where you handle the document flow with an observer, like so:

```
function transform(doc) {
  doc.extraField = 'whatever';
  return doc;
}

Meteor.publish('allDocsTransformed', function() {
  const observer = Docs.find({}).observe({
    added: (doc) => {
      this.added('collectionName', doc._id, transform(doc));
    },
    changed: (doc) => {
      this.changed('collectionName', doc._id, transform(doc));
    },
    removed: (doc) => {
      this.removed('collectionName', doc._id);
    }
  });

  this.onStop(() => observer.stop());
  this.ready();
});
```

Either way works.